# Calculate per day how many employees have requested leave

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building an application to automate the process of assigning everyone’s leave at the place I work.

One of the conditions to be able to get your requested leave, is that something we call “The Red Line” has not been reached yet. The Red Line dictates how many people are allowed to have leave on the same day, to prevent shortage of staff.

I thought about this problem very hard yesterday, and finally came up with the following code:

```
// Get data from form fields
$redline = ($_POST["redline"]);    // This sets the Red Line
$rls = strtotime($_POST["rls"]);   // This is the start of the period in which to check
$rle = strtotime($_POST["rle"]);   // This is the end of that period

$redlinereached = 0; // Always starts at 0 and counts +1 if there is a leave 'block' found within the given period

echo "<table class='DataFromDB'>

if (isset($_POST["check"])) {
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM redlinetest ORDER BY staff_id ASC");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['staff_id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . date('d-m-Y',strtotime($row['leave_start'])) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . date('d-m-Y',strtotime($row['leave_end'])) . "</td>";

        if ((strtotime($row['leave_start']) >= $rls) && (strtotime($row['leave_end']) <= $rle) or (strtotime($row['leave_end']) >= $rls) && (strtotime($row['leave_start']) <= $rle)) {
            ++$redlinereached;
            echo "<td>Yes</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td>No</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
```

[View a working example](https://www.yvojolie.nl/ns/avis/testredline.php)

Of course I was quite happy with myself after five hours of trying to get it to do what I wanted, which I thought was checking how many leave there was in a period...

Only to wake up this morning, realizing, *this is not at all what I Wanted!*
I don't need to know how many leave there is in a period, **I need to know how many leave there is every day**.

Then I need to keep track of it for all the days within the period and *‘do something’* if the Red Line has been reached.

Comment: perhaps supplying the table schema, sample data and associated javascript might make the question more complete

Comment: I'm not sure I fully follow, but here's an idea: take the earliest leave start and latest leave end. Create a `DatePeriod` object from those with a single day interval. Iterate that period and, for every day in it, check against all leaves you have fetched from the db if there's an overlap. Count the overlaps and if your limit is reached, then that day has been redlined.

Comment: First thoughts are that you really should make the dates on your database into DATE types and not text

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo code to point you in the right direction. I don't have time to test it so you'll have to figure the rest out on your own.

```
$start = new DateTime($_POST['rls']);
$end = new DateTime($_POST['rle']);
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$range = new DatePeriod($start->modify('-1 day'), $interval, $end->modify('+1 day'));

foreach ($range as $date) {
    $result = $db->query('select count(*) from redlinetest where leave_start >= $date && leave_end <= $date');
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    
    if ($row[0] >= $_POST['redline']) {
        // redline reached
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure it is. Just because you don't agree with it doesn't make it wrong. There are several ways to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: So how does you use of redlinetest comply with second normal form? How does this deal with a scenario where people don't take a full day as leave? How many round trips to the DBMS and query executions does this take to resolve? How do you calculate $range?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong. The data which you are trying to read from "redlinetest" is a representation of data which is already held elsewhere in your database. Unless "redlinetest" is a VIEW of that data, you should not be using it. It breaks fundamental rules of relational database design and results in a system that, even if it works, will be difficult to maintain.

It's good practice to start with a set of test cases before you try to design your program let alone actually write any code. You would probably have spotted the issues with your current approach much quicker.

You didn't tell us what the source data looks like. If I use this:

```
create table leave (
user_id INT NOT NULL,
start_time dateime NOT NULL,
end_time datetime NOT NULL,
status ENUM ('requested', 'approved')
)
```

(but with appropriate indexes).

The first step is to get a set of the times at which we want to count how many people are on leave between $srch_start and $srch_end. Actually, we only need to know the number *when the number of people on leave changes*, so we only need to do counts at those times...

```
SELECT l1.start_time AS event
FROM leave AS l1
WHERE l1.start_time<$search_end
AND l1.end_time>$search_start
AND l1.status='approved'
UNION
SELECT l2.end_time 
FROM leave AS l2
WHERE l2.start_time<$search_end
AND l2.end_time>$search_start
AND l2.status='approved'
```

For simplicity I'll just refer to this query as $EVENTS from here.

Then you can get a measure of the number of people on leave at any time with....

```
SELECT event.event AS at_time, COUNT(DISTINCT l.user_id), GROUP_CONCAT(l.user_id)
FROM leave AS l,
($EVENTS) AS event
WHERE l.start_time<=event.event
AND l.end_time>=event.event
AND l.status='approved'
GROUP BY event.event
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT l.user_id) DESC
```

(none of this code is tested and I'm writing it off the cuff - but hopefully you get the idea)

While I'm here anyway....this is a rather expensive query to run at scale. A more efficient solution can built using geospatial indexing but that's a much longer story.